# WordPress is responding with 400 bad request while querying for posts using ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, xmlhttprequest, wordpress-theming

In my custom Blog home page, during its initial load, I am querying for 3 posts and displaying it using `wp_query`. And on scroll I am trying to load the remaining posts 3 posts/scroll using Ajax but I am getting only 0 as the response in the front end and in my console I can see that the xhr response is `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"\r\n0","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}`. The same script is working in my other website. But here I am getting only 0 response. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? any help would much appreciated.

The loadmore script I am using is:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
  
        var pageNumber = 2;
        var ppp = 3; // Post per page
        var max_page = $("#max_page").val();
        //console.log('Taxonomy got from page: '+taxonomy);
        var str = '';
        var debounceScroll = null;
            
          
            $(window).scroll(function () {
          
              if (debounceScroll != null) {
                clearTimeout(debounceScroll);
              }
          
            debounceScroll = setTimeout(function() {
            
            if(pageNumber <= max_page){
                
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.banking-fintech__flexbox').offset().top + $('.banking-fintech__flexbox').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
                   // str = '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber + '&ppp=' + ppp + '&action=more_post_ajax';
  
                    str = {
                      action: 'more_post_ajax',
                      pageNumber: pageNumber,
                      ppp: ppp,
                  };
  
                    $("#lds-ripple").css("display", "block").delay(2000);
  
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    url: blog_ajax.ajaxurl,
                    data: str,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var $data = $(data);
                        if ($data.length) {
                            $(".banking-fintech__flexbox").append($data).delay(2000);
                            $("#lds-ripple").css("display", "none");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#lds-ripple").css("display", "none");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                        $("#lds-ripple").css("display", "none");
                    }
  
                });
                pageNumber++;
                
         return false;
            }
        }
    }, 100);
        });
    });
  });
enter code here
```

script localization

```
if (is_page_template('blog.php')) {
    wp_register_script( 'loadmore-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/loadmore.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'loadmore-script' );
    wp_localize_script('loadmore-script', 'blog_ajax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'noposts' => __('No older posts found', 'outstanding'),
        )
    );
}
```

on my archive page (blogs.php)

```
<?php 

$args2 = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'paged' => 1,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args2);

?>
    <section class="mainblock">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="heading">Other posts</h2>

            <div class="block">
                <ul class="flexbox">
                <?php if ($query->have_posts()): while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); 
                $max_page = $query->max_num_pages;
                ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class="link" href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                            <img class="img" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'); ?>" alt="" loading="lazy">
                            <div class="text">
                                <span><?php echo get_the_date('F j - Y'); ?></span> <span class="gray-dot__circle"></span> <span><?php echo gp_reading_time($post); ?>
                    read</span>
                                <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
              <?php  endwhile;
              echo '<input type="hidden" id="max_page" name="max_page" value="'.$max_page.'" />';
        endif; ?>
                </ul>
                <img id="lds-ripple" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/loading3.svg';?>" style="display: none; position: relative; width: 80px; height: 80px; margin: auto;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: plz add your wp ajax php code to your question

Comment: Added please have a look now.

Comment: You are requesting posts via ajax request, where did you handle the request?
the code should be hook with this action hook "wp_ajax_{$action}"